# "CPU is not halted" and "No APB-AP found" error

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller, cortex-m, jtag

When I use JTAG to load my C code to evaluation board, it loads successfully. However, when I executed my code from main(), I immediately got "CPU is not halted" error, followed by "No APB-AP found" error.

I was able to load and executed the USB-related code before I got this error.

I googled for it and use JTAG command "rx 0" to reset the target, but it does not make any change.

I am using ARM Cortex-M3 Processor, J-Link ARM V4.14d, IAR Embedded workbench IDE.

Thanks for ur help.

Comment: Are you sure that `main()` is the entry point? There is usually a fair amount of startup code that must be executed to set up memory addressing, initialize hardware, set up a stack pointer, and so forth before you can begin doing things like setting up the C runtime library, let alone actually calling `main()`.

Comment: IAR will execute the startup code and insert a breakpoint at main(). But I got the error when I keep going from main().

Answer (score 3):

One possibility: **watchdog**

If your hardware has a watchdog, then you must ensure that it does not reset the CPU when the JTAG wants to halt it. If the watchdog resets the CPU you would typically get a "CPU not halted" type of error you described.

If the CPU has an internal watchdog circuit, on some CPUs it is automatically "paused" when the JTAG halts the CPU. But on others, that doesn't happen, and you need to ensure the watchdog is disabled while doing JTAG debugging.

If your circuit has a watchdog circuit that is external to the CPU, then typically you need to be able to disable it in some way (typically the hardware designer provides some sort of switch/jumper on the board to do so).

Answer (score 0):

are you re-using the jtag lines as gpio lines and clobbering the jtags ability to communicate with the chip?  I bricked a stellaris board that way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this line in code:

WatchdogStallEnable(WATCHDOG0_BASE);    // stop the watchdog when CPU stopped